# Laravel 5.0 Elequent Group By Related Table Field

Tags: laravel-5

I have 2 model

Category :

```
 public function transaction()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
}
```

Transactions :

```
    public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

And i build a table contain column Category, Month and Total (transaction)

In Controller :

```
$cats =  Category::all();
```

As Result In View :
(while in view I looping foreach for transactions->created_at and format it  , so it will show the month Word instead numbers)

[image: Sample View]

The problem is , how to make it the month is in group, so it will not looping by same month , same happen to total , it will group ; total qty .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a one to many relationship (Category has many Transactions), if you want to show transaction properties while iterating in categories, you will need to aggregate the fields in the collection (transactions).

For the Total field which is a number, the solution is simple with [Laravel's sum() function of a collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sum), assuming this is what you intend.

As for the months, it depends on what you want to show on the Month column and then decide what aggregation function to use to manipulate the created_at of each transaction. You cannot add up the dates via sum function but you might want to do some custom calculation so consider using [the reduce function of a collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-reduce).